# Should work experience section of Linkedin profile include accomplishment or just tell a story about yourself

Tags: work-experience, linkedin

**Important Notice**

Here we are **not** discussing whether to include accomplishments with numbers in a *Resume/CV* (See [Contributions in a CV for developers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136901/contributions-in-a-cv-for-developers)) because it seems necessary nowadays.

Should the work experience section of the LinkedIn profile

1. include accomplishments with numbers (such as Accomplished [X] as measured by [Y], by doing [Z])
   or
2. just tell a story about yourself.

**Tell a story about yourself**

Some people suggest you tell a story about yourself.

> The target audience doesn't care about it. [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119287081)

**Include accomplishment**

Some people encourage to include accomplishment. [2](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-write-experience-section-linkedin-profile-5-examples-nikita-gupta/)

We are trying to understand which one we should choose.

**Update 2024-2-4**

@nvoigt: Thank you for your reply.

Before posting, some posts are checked using SE search but didn't find yours. Your post is awesome and the toilet paper example is interesting.

However, this post is not duplicated because this post is *not* asking **if a resume should include accomplishment by numbers**, which seems necessary nowadays.

Instead, this post is asking (and hoping to clarify) **if the work experience section of LinkedIn profile should include accomplishment by numbers** (such as a resume).

@mhoran_psprep gave a [helpful answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/195371/118973). Recommended to read.

**Update 2024-2-24**
@keshlam: Please kindly see the update on 2024-2-4 above. Thank you.

@mhoran_psprep: Your answer is helpful. We appreciate your help and upvote.

> There are two main purposes of accounts on LinkedIn.

> Networking

> Finding a job

**Update 2024-2-25**

@keshlam: Thank you for giving feedback. Another interpretation of the question is that LinkedIn is a CV or a story of yourself.

Comment: Related (duplicate in my view, but I didn't want to make it so myself, since it's mine) https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136901/contributions-in-a-cv-for-developers

Comment: There is an implicit assumption in this question that there is "one right way" to do things. I would strongly argue there is not, and the answer depends on circumstances.

Comment: If the numbers are impressive, quote the numbers. If they aren't...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contributions in a CV for developers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136901/contributions-in-a-cv-for-developers)

Comment: @keshlam: unfortunately, it doesn't. Your link is actually nvoigt's link on 2/4. The reason was mentioned in the update section on 2/4 too. at future viewers: so please don't close and downvote. (crying face)

Comment: In my opinion, the work section of LinkedIn *is* another CV. But you aren't required to treat it that way; if you'd rather not., don't. There are no formal requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Thee are two main purposes of accounts on LinkedIn.

- Networking
- Finding a job

In the first case, networking, the idea is to provide enough information so that when former (or current ) co-worked looks at your account they know it is the person they are looking for. They look at the names of the companies, and the dates, and say that has to be the same person I worked with 10 years ago, because all the information seems to match. They don't care how much money you saved the company, or how fast the the improved process was.

In the job search case, they will want to see those types of things so that when the search algorithm finds you, they are getting enough information to know if they should initiate contact. They need more than companies, project, and dates. They want to see what you accomplished. They want to see the tools your worked with.

The networking goal means list all the companies/jobs. The job search goal means those sections need details. So do both.